# Find the tangential acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, centrifugal-force, centripetal-force

> *A racing car driver drives his car on a flat circular track of radius $\frac{25}3 m$ and a coefficient of friction $0.5$. Find the magnitude of its tangential acceleration (in $ms^{-2}$) at an instant when car starts slipping at a speed of $5 ms^{-1}$.*

I found the centripetal acceleration to be $3ms^{-2}$ and thought about setting the resultant acceleration (vector sum of centripetal acceleration + tangential acceleration) = $\mu$$g$ where $\mu$ = 0.5 but I don't think it is correct. If it is, then can somebody please explain why?

By the way, I am getting the correct answer (=$5ms^{-2}$) by this method.

Comment: I am just getting the answer but I don't know why is this method correct.

Comment: Why would it be wrong?

Comment: How does that method yield that answer?

Answer (score 1):

Sit in the frame of car if you are having problems. Apply tangential and centrifugal pseudo forces. As we are at rest, friction has to act of same magnitude of their resultant and in opposite direction. The answer will be $4ms^{-2}$

$0.5 \times 10=\sqrt{3^2+a_t^2}$

$a_t=4ms^{-2}$

Comment: Could you please provide a free body diagram for your solution?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be wrong. If they want to know tangential acceleration, they should have given angular acceleration. From given things , 'r' , 'v', and "mu" we can only find centripetal acceleration. And as you said you are getting answer 5 m/s². How it is possible?